# How to import bencode cleanly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, importerror, bencoding

**I'm trying to use bdecode from the bencode library that is to say this:**

```
def bdecode(x):
    try:
        r, l = decode_func[x[0]](x, 0)
    except (IndexError, KeyError, ValueError):
        raise BTFailure("not a valid bencoded string")
    if l != len(x):
        raise BTFailure("invalid bencoded value (data after valid prefix)")
    return r

from types import StringType, IntType, LongType, DictType, ListType, TupleType
```

**Located here in the init :**

[image]

**But with my code de i can't have any result because of an error. Indeed the import dont find bdecode but i don't understand why.
This is the simple code and the error output:**

```
from bencode import *

blabla = 'd8:announce70:http://tracker.t411.io:56969/c5faa6720249d33ff6ba2af48640af89/announce7:comment29:https://www.t411.io/t/524280210:created by19:https://www.t411.io13:creation datei1431685353e4:infod6:lengthi14634059e4:name22:Charlie-Hebdo-1178.pdf12:piece lengthi262144e6:pieces1120:'
myprint = bdecode(blabla)
print myprint
```

[image]

*For information on the bencode installation i just made "pip install bencode"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called your program `bencode.py` this masks the installed library. Rename your script and try again:

Better:

```
import bencode

bencode.bdecode(string_to_decode)
```